# JSONP in NPM module (Node/Browser) Cross domain

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, cross-domain, jsonp

I'm writing an NPM module supposed to work both in Node and on the browser (packed via Browserify).

Part of its functionality is to execute a JSONP call, and to return the parsed data.
I can't get it to work. 
I tried using the `jsonp-client` and `jsonp` npm modules, to little avail.

`node-jsonp`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-jsonp

```
promise = new promise (resolve, reject) ->

        nodejsonp url, (json) ->
            resolve json
```

The snippet above works fine in Node, but in the browser fails because of the Same Origin cross domain security policy.

`jsonp-client` https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonp-client

```
promise = new promise (resolve, reject) ->
        jsonpclient url, (err, data) ->
            if (err)
                console.log err
            resolve data
```

In this case I get the error "Error: Could not find callback on URL(…)", but I can't understand from the documentation how to properly implement the functionality.

Little help? :)

Edit: The first package mentioned is actually "node-jsonp" and not "jsonp"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you use their API incorrect. Api for [first one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonp) package is: `jsonp(url, opts, fn)`, so you should rewrite your code and add opts:

```
promise = new promise (resolve, reject) ->
    jsonp url, {}, (json) ->
        resolve json
```

[Second one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonp-client) have this in documentation:

> On the browser you must supply a valid callback on the URL.

It requires [manual adding of callback](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonp-client#callbacks) parameter to URL. You should check [how jsonp works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP): it adds `callback` GET parameter and response wrapped in calling of this callback function. I.e.

- you are sendind request: `<api url>?callback=cb`;
- server renders javascript response, that will be `eval`-ed in your application `cb({json});`
- for handling of this response you should have *global* function `cb`, that will receive json as argument.

Comment: Hi Alexandr, thanks fo looking into this.
Regarding your first suggestion, my bad, the package is used for that was actually "node-jsonp", which according to their docs accepts that syntax too. Still, cross domain issue, no luck.

Regarding your second suggestion, is it a good approach defining a global callback to be used by NPM package? I was hoping there would be a less invasive approach :)